# multithreading in ASP.Net webservice - what happens after the main thread completes?

Tags: multithreading, web-services, asmx

I have inherited a set of legacy webservices (VB.Net, IIS hosted ASMX) in which some of the WebMethods are using basic multithreading.

It seems like they have done this to allow the WebMethod to return to the client quicker with a response, while still doing some longer running operations that do not impact the response object itself (such as cleanup operations, logging, etc).

My question is, what happens in this webservice when the main thread (that which created the WebMethod instance) completes? Do these other threads terminate or does it actually block the main thread from completing if the other threads are not complete? Or, do the threads run to completion on the IIS process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads are independent of each other unless one thread waits on another. Once created, there is nothing stopping the request (main) thread from completing, and any other threads simply complete on their own.